# Make s3 not list files when pointing to index directory

Tags: amazon-s3, directory, amazon-cloudfront

I have a bucket in s3 called `site.cdn`. I have also added a DNS record so instead of using the whole big url of cloudfront or s3 i will use `cdn.site.com` but when i point this address into the browser it lists all files from that bucket...

How can i make sure s3 wont display any files when on the index directory of the bucket?

Answer (score 1):

Make the bucket private, but set the individual files as public.